# rerunning retrofit2 rxjava Observable

Tags: rx-java, observable, retrofit2

Given a somewhat generic Retrofit2 Rxjava call like this:

```
mMbtaApi.getFullAlerts(ApiConfig.MBTA_API_KEY)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.subscribe(alerts -> {
                                mAlerts = alerts;
                                mAlertListSubject.onNext(getFilteredAlerts());
                                mLoadSubscription.unsubscribe();
                            },
                            err -> {
                                mAlertListSubject.onError(err);
                                mLoadSubscription.unsubscribe();
                            });
```

How do you re-execute it?
I thought something like this would do it (a subscribe alone should do it but I added the unsubscribe just in case):

```
alerts = mMbtaApi.getFullAlerts(ApiConfig.MBTA_API_KEY)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())

alerts.unsubscribe(handler)
alerts.subscribe(handler)
```

But I don't see any network traffic go out when I do the second subscribe.
The alert HTTP return headers indicate that the data should not be cached:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires -1
```

so it's definitely not okhttp caching the data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  I was creating the okhttpclient like so:

```
final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
return builder.cache(new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize)).build()
```

Taking out the .cache() now makes it go over the network.  Not sure why the cache ignores the "no-cache" directives in the http headers though...seems wrong :-(